# Does WebDriver Manager also working for Appium?

Tags: selenium, appium

Is there any Appium manager like the webdriver [manager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager) for using? since the appium is implements the Webdriver so..is it there?
Or maybe there is option to use it for Appium drivers too? (Android driver  - IOS driver)
[image]
Thank you

Comment: in appium these drivers comes inbuild you don't have to install the drivers manually as in webapp testing. Could you elaborate what you are trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to download a "driver" for appium. The drivers comes with the appium package for hybrid and native app testing.

[image]

so once you initialize the driver capabilities , appium will automatically install the reuired driver on the device and allows appium server to communicate with the device through xcuitest or uiautomator apis

Comment: so after you install Appium, you actualy gets automaticly the Driver for that?
because I saw that you need to add the capabilities first and than 
`URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub");
driver = new AppiumDriver(url, dc);`
but before that you create either `AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;`
or either `IOSDriver<MobileElement> driver` or either `AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;`
so where they are come from?

Comment: AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(capabilities);

Comment: you specify url of the appium server , not the driver. Appium will handle everything including the installation and communication between the driver. if you don't specify the URL then a local appium instance will be spawn up else the remote appium given on the specific URL will be considered

Comment: So actualy if I understand you, when I install the Appium client (through npm or CLI) actualy I download the driver too?

Comment: yes appium handles everything for you , you are not  passing any driver path or something to the appium server . You only pass the platform capability

Comment: you are istalling appium server not client , appium doesn't need a client as it uses rest API. You use client libraries to talk to these endpoints , same in selenium . import appium , import selenium extra are libraries that has code that talks to this rest apis

Comment: Thank you, Now I understand it how it works , looks like that the exe is just for opening the server and in Appium you do it manualy

Comment: @nuzooo in appium also you will just give the capabilities , you don't give any path to actual driver location .

Comment: right, in Appium I don't give the exe because I do it manualy, in PC = chrome, I give the path for the exe just so I don't need to open the server manualy if I understand you correct